# Typesafety in a function that accepts callback function in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code in TS playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MAUBKFA+dBvAWACgYYAjAQwCcAuGQk0mACwEs6BWY0gXwBpuMCKwAedBkxgBbCmJgBGAAyCexHhmLE4AVzDAorcDCgBTaGjhg6mHDABKJ0FQAmAHmhVWYAOZ8YAeTIAK0cobCwJGCoTKG0qMHgwTDVNIlBIWDxhET8oaJMYHhRjMygLRA0iYnSIEAAbEwA6OpBvNDyTEwwgA)

In line 14, is it possible to throw error for "tree" variable, i.e. it does not exist in the returned object for it to be destructured ?

```
const foo = () => ({
  bar: {
    hi: 5
  },
  six: {
    max: 10
  }
})

function test(fn: () => Record<string, Object>) {
  return fn()
}

const {six, tree } = test(foo) // <- line 14

console.log(tree)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with the use of generics you can:

```js
function test<R extends Record<string, Object>>(fn: () => R): R {
    return fn()
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MAUBKFA+dBvAWACgZSYAjAQwCcAuGQks5gCwEt6BWY5gXwBoeZCGwAe9Rs2YBbSuJgBGAAxDSvYrwzFicAK5hgUNuBhQAptAA8AJRhnR5sABMIMa2dDUnl6NTZgAc34YAHlyACsPKGxsNDgwekwcNwx6W0kyajMoXWoweDBMDW0iUEhYPBgRUWCoLLMYXhRTCyg4xC0iYjKIEAAbMwA6PpAAtDqzMwwgA)